# how do i display image with a specific file name using part of the file name

Tags: php

I am working on a project where a lot of images are uploaded. Image name is saved as follows;
`$target_file = $target_dir .$Property_number . basename($_FILES["sittingroom"]["name"]);`

i want to display images that have thesame $Property_number. So i used fnmatch() search for '62c8706c06bf2' but in return i get images with 62a456ggfrshg, 62bu737778384 and so on. I think this happens because the first two string matches. but i want is only when the whole search string is contained in the image name.

i used glob() but i think that is worst coz it didnt match anything. maybe i did it wrong. I need help please. I have searched but couldnt get anything that will help.

```
<?php

$detg = '62c8706c06bf2';
$imagesDirectory = "singlerooms/";
if(is_dir($imagesDirectory))
{
    $opendirectory = opendir($imagesDirectory);
    while (($image = readdir($opendirectory)) !== false)
    {
        if(($image == '.') || ($image == '..'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        $imgFileType = pathinfo($image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
        if(($imgFileType == 'jpg') || ($imgFileType == 'png')){
            fnmatch($image, $detg, $imagesDirectory = 0);{
            echo ("<img src='singlerooms/".$image."' width='150' > ");
      }
   }
 }
   closedir($opendirectory);
};

?>
```

Comment: Please @AD7six, i am more confused reading your remark. I am learning, if you can be a bit specific, i would appreciate that.  how do i use glob in this my code or if there is a better way of doing this

Comment: @AD7six, i have passed $image to fnmatch but all the images is showing. Is my fnmatch code correct? I went through the reference links, they used glob  but it is not for image. I tried glob but it gives file names only not image. I used '   ' in fnmatch thinking it will check all image content and get the correct image.

Comment: For what it's worth you should simply omit the third parameter `fnmatch()`. It's optional, and the default is zero (no flags set). The way you've written your code, you overwrite `$imagesDirectory .` **PRO TIP** Get yourself a decent IDE like WebStorm (available to individuals for short money) or VS Code. It will catch problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, try this:

```
if(($imgFileType=='jpg' || $imgFileType=='png') && strpos($image, $detg)!==false )
    echo "<img src='singlerooms/".$image."' width='150' > ";
```

Comment: yep, that does the trick

Comment: @Eder Rocha, perfectly solved it, thanks and remain blessed